# Phonegap geolocation GPS threshold

Tags: jquery, cordova, gps

I am build an exercise app with phonegap and jquery with [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/build-an-exercise-tracking-app-persistence-graphing/)
All works just fine but there is a problem with the gps location that jumps from time to time, and as a results I have issues with track because it looks like i have passed a long way (As you can see in the image attached.

The way I am try to resolved this is to check the average of lat and lng and make sure that the next sample will be no higher then the average of the lat or lng (depends what i am checking).
After knowing what is the average, I am checking the change rate of the last sample from the sample before and if it is bigger, I would like to set position.coords.lngitude / position.coords.latitude to the maximum rate that i have computed.

But It seems to not work for me...

Here is the code:

```
$("#stepslink_start").live('click', function() {
    $("#stepslink_stop").hide();

    // Start tracking the User
    watch_id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
            // Success
                    function(position) {
                        // Gets the current lat and lng
                        lat = position.coords.latitude;
                        lng = position.coords.longitude;
                        // Push that lat each one in to his array
                        last_2_points_lat.push(lat);
                        last_2_points_lng.push(lng);
                        // Checks if the array length is biger then 2 items and if so starts the process of compering the lat and lng to the average
                        if (last_2_points_lat.length > 2 | last_2_points_lng.length > 2) {
                            // Delete the items of the array that has created before the last 2 items
                            last_2_points_lat.splice(0, 1);
                            last_2_points_lng.splice(0, 1);
                            // resets the variables
                            sum_lat = 0;
                            sum_lng = 0;
                            avg_lat = 0;
                            avg_lng = 0;
                            avg_change_lat = 0;
                            avg_change_lng = 0;
                            /*
                             * Lat Function
                             */
                            // Sum the values of the array
                            for (i = 0; i < last_2_points_lat.length; i++) {
                                if (i < 3) {
                                    sum_lat += last_2_points_lat[i];
                                }
                            }
                            // Checks if the array has 2 items
                            if (last_2_points_lat.length >= 2) {
                                avg_lat = sum_lat / last_2_points_lat.length;
                                // Checks if the lat is larger then average lat
                                if (Math.abs(last_2_points_lat[last_2_points_lat.length - 1]) > Math.abs(avg_lat)) {
                                    // Calculate the average change of the lat
                                    avg_change_lat = (avg_lat - last_2_points_lat[last_2_points_lat.length - 1]) / last_2_points_lat[last_2_points_lat.length - 1];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (Math.abs(lat - last_2_points_lat[last_2_points_lat.length - 1]) / Math.abs(lat) <= Math.abs(avg_change_lat)) {
                            current_change_rate = (lat - last_2_points_lat[last_2_points_lat.length - 1]) / (lat);
                            console.log(current_change_rate);
                            if (current_change_rate > 0) {
                                position.coords.latitude = lat * (1 + ((lat - (last_2_points_lat[last_2_points_lat.length - 1])) / ((last_2_points_lat[last_2_points_lat.length - 1]))));
                            } else {
                                position.coords.latitude = lat * ((lat - (last_2_points_lat[last_2_points_lat.length - 1])) / ((last_2_points_lat[last_2_points_lat.length - 1])));
                            }
                        }
                        /*
                         * Lng Function
                         */
                        // Sum the values of the array
                        for (i = 0; i < last_2_points_lng.length; i++) {
                            if (i < 3) {
                                sum_lng += last_2_points_lng[i];
                            }
                        }
                        // Checks if the array has 2 items
                        if (last_2_points_lng.length >= 2) {
                            avg_lng = sum_lng / last_2_points_lng.length;
                            // Checks if the lng is larger then average lng
                            if (Math.abs(last_2_points_lng[last_2_points_lng.length - 1]) > Math.abs(avg_lng)) {
                                // Calculnge the average change of the lng
                                avg_change_lng = (avg_lng - last_2_points_lng[last_2_points_lng.length - 1]) / last_2_points_lng[last_2_points_lng.length - 1];
                            }
                        }
                        if (Math.abs(lng - last_2_points_lng[last_2_points_lng.length - 1]) / Math.abs(lng) <= Math.abs(avg_change_lng)) {
                            current_change_rate = (lng - last_2_points_lng[last_2_points_lng.length - 1]) / (lng);
                            console.log(current_change_rate);
                            if (current_change_rate > 0) {
                                position.coords.lngitude = lng * (1 + ((lng - (last_2_points_lng[last_2_points_lng.length - 1])) / ((last_2_points_lng[last_2_points_lng.length - 1]))));
                            } else {
                                position.coords.lngitude = lng * ((lng - (last_2_points_lng[last_2_points_lng.length - 1])) / ((last_2_points_lng[last_2_points_lng.length - 1])));
                            }
                        }
                        tracking_data.push(position);

                    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the same when real-world testing my app - that both Android and iOS will intermittently deliver wildly inaccurate positions while using GPS. I solved this by using the position accuracy, passed as part of the W3C Position spec, to filter out positions that were not accurate enough. Try something like this:

```
var MinimumAccuracy = 20; // metres

// Start tracking the User
watch_id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
  // Success
  function(position) {
    // Reject udpate if accuracy is not sufficient
    if(position.coords.accuracy > MinimumAccuracy){
        console.warn("Position update rejected because accuracy of"+position.coords.accuracy+"m is less than required "+MinimumAccuracy+"m");
        return;
    }

    // Else, get the current lat and lng
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;

  }, etc...
);
```